# Stream.Read: EOF vs 0 count

Tags: c#, stream

The [documentation for `Stream.Read`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.read?view=netcore-2.0#System_IO_Stream_Read_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_) says that:

> Read returns 0 **only** when there is no more data in the stream **and** no more is expected (such as a closed socket or end of file)

From here, it is clear that `Read` should not return 0 even if 0 is passed to `count` parameter.

But I tested this with `MemoryStream` and it returns 0:

```
var mem = new MemoryStream(new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4});
var buf = new byte[0];
var ret = mem.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
Console.WriteLine(ret); // prints 0
```

Does that mean the documentation is missing something?
Can an implementation throw an exception if `count` is 0?

Comment: I'd guess at a documentation problem. I would think it should be *valid*, but pointless to call the method with a count of 0.

Comment: IIRC the Remarks section isn't part of documentation proper (that is, not part of the *contractual* behaviour). It just gives a few guidelines and explanations of design decisions etc. Note also the "The implementation will block until at least one byte of data can be read" which would also be false in your case. As for exceptions, any implementation can throw whatever it wants, but a well-behaved derived class will avoid throwing exceptions (that should be handled at call-site, mind you) not defined on the base class. `count == 0` is a valid argument, so a good implementation won't throw.

Comment: *"it is clear that Read should not return 0 even if 0 is passed to count"* - why? The method returns any amount less or equal of requested. Since there is no number less - you will always get 0 or exception (e.g. `TimeoutException`). And as @Luaan noted, this can be used to *block* until there is something available to read without actually reading a single byte from buffer.

Comment: @Sinatr yes the returns tag of the documentation is correct: `The total number of bytes read into the buffer. This can be less than the number of bytes requested if that many bytes are not currently available, or zero (0) if the end of the stream has been reached.`. It is the remarks which is incorrect/confusing as it says 0 is returned **only** when no more data and no more expected (notice `only`)

Comment: Lol what a funny question, but I kinda agree though. I think it will be better to returns `-1` in case of EOF.

Comment: @ThariqNugrohotomo Well, it would be better if it returned a value that could either be "number of bytes returned" or "end of stream" rather than a plain integer :) But given the circumstances, zero isn't a poor choice - consider that you almost always read from a stream in a loop; if you mistakenly read a count of zero, you'd be spinning *forever*. Zero is a lot safer as an exit value :)

Answer (score 0):

You have requested 0 bytes, so `Read` function just reads zero bytes.

Output is 0, and it is based on [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.read?view=netcore-2.0#System_IO_Stream_Read_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_):

> #### Returns
>
> The total number of bytes read into the buffer. This
>   can be less than the number of bytes requested if that many bytes are
>   not currently available, or zero (0) if the end of the stream has been
>   reached.

Zero is 'number of bytes requested', in your example

Comment: But as the OP highlights in their question, the documentation states that 0 is returned **only** if the end of the stream has been reached, which is clearly untrue here since a subsequent non-zero read will return more bytes.